# Mods & Liability Insurance

Tags: transmission, swap

I want to do a pretty major transmission/drivetrain swap on my car, but I have a few questions about insurance. I've been told that if I got into an accident my insurance could refuse to pay for the damages if they discover that the car has mods. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

So tell them of the mods.

They will make note of them and will either change the price of cover or it may stay the same.

Can’t tell you how much as « it depends » so don’t ask.

Comment: Agreed - it may vary according to which country you are in, but most places you are legally required to inform your insurance company of any modifications - and not only will they refuse to pay out if you have an accident, but you may also be prosecuted for driving without valid insurance...

Answer (score 1):

Some companies may want to do an inspection or send you to an official MOD place to have the work inspected and signed off as safe.

Unless your swapping over like for like gearbox / transmission than you need to notify of any mods no matter how small they're